# Incorrect count in pivot table query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the two table with some records as shown below in sql fiddle.

My sample data is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_One](
    [ID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Col1] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ColumnDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ColumnTime] [time](7) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_two](
    [Slno] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Date1] [datetime] NULL,
    [Time1] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date2] [datetime] NULL,
    [Time2] [datetime] NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[test_two] ([Slno], [ID], [Name], [Date1], [Time1], [Date2], [Time2]) VALUES (N'115', N'47', N'DateOne', CAST(0x0000901A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000000000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000901B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00000000018B3BB0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[test_two] ([Slno], [ID], [Name], [Date1], [Time1], [Date2], [Time2]) VALUES (N'116', N'47', N'DateTwo', CAST(0x0000901C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000000000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000901D00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x00000000018B3BB0 AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'782', CAST(0x0000901A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x070075033F430000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11602', N'504', CAST(0x0000901A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07809A19CB4B0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11603', N'110', CAST(0x0000901A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0700C02F57540000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11604', N'634', CAST(0x0000901A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0780E545E35C0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'400', CAST(0x0000901B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07002D2255650000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'376', CAST(0x0000901B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07804A62F8430000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11602', N'989', CAST(0x0000901B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07007078844C0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11602', N'949', CAST(0x0000901B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0780958E10550000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11603', N'111', CAST(0x0000901C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0700DD6A825D0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11603', N'840', CAST(0x0000901C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x078002810E660000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11603', N'217', CAST(0x0000901C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x070020C1B1440000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11604', N'420', CAST(0x0000901C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x078045D73D4D0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11604', N'333', CAST(0x0000901D00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07008DB3AF550000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11604', N'782', CAST(0x0000901D00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0780B2C93B5E0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11604', N'504', CAST(0x0000901D00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0700D8DFC7660000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11604', N'110', CAST(0x0000901D00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0780F51F6B450000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'634', CAST(0x0000901E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07003DFCDC4D0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11604', N'400', CAST(0x0000901E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0780621269560000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'376', CAST(0x0000901E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07008828F55E0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'989', CAST(0x0000901E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x070047936D670000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11603', N'949', CAST(0x0000901F00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x078064D310460000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11604', N'111', CAST(0x0000901F00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07008AE99C4E0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'840', CAST(0x0000901F00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0700F2ADFE560000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'217', CAST(0x0000901F00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07005A72605F0000 AS Time))
INSERT [dbo].[test_One] ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], [ColumnDate], [ColumnTime]) VALUES (N'47', N'11601', N'420', CAST(0x0000901F00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0700C236C2670000 AS Time))
```

Query I've tried:

```
SELECT col1,Total,TGrp,AvailableIn,[DateOne],[DateTwo],(Total - ([DateOne]+[DateTwo])) as Others
FROM                     
(
    SELECT  v.col1,g.Name as Name,c.Total as Total,
    x.AvailableIn,
    (select count(distinct Name) from test_two) TGrp
    FROM test_one AS v   
    INNER JOIN test_two g ON g.ID= '47' 
    AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.ColumnDate, 106))
                                                + CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.ColumnTime, 108)) >= g.Date1
                                                + g.Time1
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.ColumnDate, 106))
                                                + CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.ColumnTime, 108)) <= g.Date2
                                                + g.Time2
                                        )                                                            
    inner join
    (
        select col1,count(*) as Total
        FROM test_one 
        group by col1
    ) c 
    on c.col1 = v.col1
    join
    (
        select ID,count(Available) AS AvailableIn
        from
        (
            select ID,CASE WHEN Name IN('DateOne','DateTwo') THEN 1 END AS Available
            from test_two
        ) as pt
        group by ID
    ) x
    on x.ID= '47'
) p                     
PIVOT                
(            
    count(Name)                        
    FOR Name IN ( [DateOne],[DateTwo] )                        
) AS pvt
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4678/1

**Expected Result**:

```
col1   Total  TGrp  AvailableIn  DateOne  DateTwo  Others              
---------------------------------------------------------
11601   9      2        1           3        0       6
11602   3      2        1           3        0       0
11603   5      2        2           1        3       1
11604   8      2        2           1        5       2
```

**Explanation of Above result**: The result is correct in `AvailableIn` column it is showing the available groups, for first row the count is `1` because `DateOne` column is having value. Likewise for others.

But Getting result is:

```
col1   Total  TGrp  AvailableIn  DateOne  DateTwo  Others              
---------------------------------------------------------
11601   9      2        2           3        0       6
11602   3      2        2           3        0       0
11603   5      2        2           1        3       1
11604   8      2        2           1        5       2
```

**Note**: The Problem is in `AvailableIn` column which is giving wrong count in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not counting the `AvailableIN` for each `col1`, you are basically getting a total count of the `DateOne` and `DateTwo` which equals 2 because you have 2 values in `test_two`.  I'd rewrite your query to something similar to:

```
;with data as
(
    select 
        v.Col1,
        Total = (select count(*) from dbo.test_One t where v.Col1 = t.Col1),
        TGrp = (select count(distinct Name) from test_two),
        g.Name
    from dbo.test_One v
    INNER JOIN test_two g 
        ON g.ID= '47' 
        AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.ColumnDate, 106))
                                                    + CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.ColumnTime, 108)) >= g.Date1
                                                    + g.Time1
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.ColumnDate, 106))
                                                    + CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.ColumnTime, 108)) <= g.Date2
                                                    + g.Time2
                                            )           
)
select 
    Col1,
    Total,
    TGrp,
    AvailableIN,
    DateOne,
    DateTwo,
    Others = (Total - ([DateOne]+[DateTwo]))
from
(
    select 
        Col1,
        Total,
        TGrp,
        Name,
        AvailableIN = (select COUNT(distinct name) 
                        from data a 
                        where a.Col1 = d.Col1 
                        group by a.Col1) 
    from data d
) src
pivot
(
    count(Name)
    for Name in (DateOne, DateTwo)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4678/4). This uses some correlated subqueries to get the counts for each `col1` values and gives a result:

```
|  COL1 | TOTAL | TGRP | AVAILABLEIN | DATEONE | DATETWO | OTHERS |
|-------|-------|------|-------------|---------|---------|--------|
| 11601 |     9 |    2 |           1 |       3 |       0 |      6 |
| 11602 |     3 |    2 |           1 |       3 |       0 |      0 |
| 11603 |     5 |    2 |           2 |       1 |       3 |      1 |
| 11604 |     8 |    2 |           2 |       1 |       5 |      2 |
```